# Convert from Id to Sobject

Tags: apex, convert

I have the following scenario. I have this method:

```
 public Id picklistTechUpId {get; set;}
 public void selectTechnicalUpgradeAndPassValues(){
    System.debug('picklistShipToID: '+ picklistShipToId);
    System.debug('picklistFillerID: '+ picklistFillerId);
    System.debug('picklistTechUpID: '+ picklistTechUpId);
    if( String.isNotBlank(picklistShipToId) && String.isNotBlank(picklistFillerId) && String.isNotBlank(picklistTechUpId) ){
        offeredSolution.Ship_to_TU__c = picklistShipToId;
        offeredSolution.Filler_TU__c = picklistFillerId;
        offeredSolution.Technical_Upgrade__c = picklistTechUpId;
    }

}
```

And I want to convert the variable "**picklistTechUpId**" which is declared as a id to an SObject. Why I want to do that? Well because this variable is taking the id of a record(which is an Account) and I want to use it in my Visualforce Page. What I want to do is to take this variable, convert it to SObject of type Account and then access its fields, like Account Name, Type, Industry and so on... Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast (or convert) an Id variable to an sObject one but you can use the Id to query for the Account if you want to display its Name, Type, Industry and so on. You could do so like this:

```
 public Id picklistTechUpId {get; set;}
 public Account pickedAccount {get; set;}

 public void selectTechnicalUpgradeAndPassValues()
 {
    if( String.isNotBlank(picklistShipToId) && 
        String.isNotBlank(picklistFillerId) && 
        String.isNotBlank(picklistTechUpId) )
    {
        offeredSolution.Ship_to_TU__c = picklistShipToId;
        offeredSolution.Filler_TU__c = picklistFillerId;
        offeredSolution.Technical_Upgrade__c = picklistTechUpId;
        //The following assumes the picklistTechUpId is a valid Account Id in your org, if this is not granted, you would have to use a List<Account> for the query result and validate it is not empty before assigning the first row to your pickedAccount variable
        pickedAccount = [SELECT Id,
                             Name,
                             Type,
                             Industry
                             FROM Account
                             WHERE Id = :this.picklistTechUpId];
    }

}
```

What is not clear to me from the snippet you posted is how you are assigning the value for picklistTeckUpId?

Comment: It worked like this! Thanks :)